# What rd.live.image means?

Tags: fedora, dracut

I've recently started to use Fedora more. I want to understand boot options. I'm currently unable to find meaning of `rd.live.image`. Where is it documented?

[dracut.cmdline - dracut kernel command line options](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html) mentions it only in below and an example:

> Deprecated, renamed Options
> Here is a list of options, which were used in dracut prior to
> version 008, and their new replacement.
>
> ```
>   liveimg
>        rd.live.image
> ```

```
   Example.

   menuentry 'Live Fedora 20' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
       set isolabel=Fedora-Live-LXDE-x86_64-20-1
       set isofile="/boot/iso/Fedora-Live-LXDE-x86_64-20-1.iso"
       loopback loop $isofile
       linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz0 boot=isolinux iso-scan/filename=$isofile root=live:LABEL=$isolabel ro rd.live.image quiet rhgb
       initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd0.img
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [parameter parsing in dracut](https://github.com/dracutdevs/dracut/blob/master/modules.d/90dmsquash-live/parse-dmsquash-live.sh), it exists largely as a flag to make the dracut modules look in the `root=` for a live image instead of a normal root filesystem, to support the legacy liveimg setting.  The correct modern syntax is to just use `root=live:…`  to indicate it’s a live image.

That’s probably why it isn’t documented, it doesn’t really do anything except allow a legacy option to work.

Comment: Tried to boot removing it, as a consequence got login prompt, not desktop (auto-login to live user?). BTW username "Fedora" and neither blank not "Fedora" password is accepted. Google finds posts about much less recent versions (read about blank there), e.g. https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?288655-Fedora-18-live-USB-How-do-I-log-in

Comment: I'm booting https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/cinnamon/. The line is `linuxefi /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz root=live:CDLABEL=:... `

Comment: Booted with `rd.live.image`, username is `liveuser`, autologin to GUI, pass is blank (logged in on tty2).

Comment: It seems that `rd.live.image` doesn’t do anything else **for dracut**, but does change the behavior of something else in the Fedora startup.  It might be documented elsewhere, but it isn’t going to show up in the dracut documentation.

Comment: "Here is a list of options, which were used in dracut prior to
       version 008, and their new replacement....liveimg
           rd.live.image"  hints it is a dracut option, boot page https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/install-guide/advanced/Boot_Options from where I jumped to `dracut` does not mention `rd.live.image`.

Comment: Probably worth filing a bug against the dracut docs, although maybe the fedora docs need updated as well.

Comment: The page "https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/install-guide/advanced/Boot_Options/#sect-boot-options-available" has `edit` button - so is it that everybody is welcome to improve docs that way? If so I may try to find out about the option and add it.